# Including the '$' sign when exporting from org-mode Babel?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am writing a tech book using org-mode. I want to export to markdown (GitHub Flavored) code and results and it works fine. But I also want to export the `$` or whatever comes before (e.g. `(venv) $` when I type something in the terminal.

Now I have this:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :exports both
  python --version
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: Python 3.6.2
```

Which gets exported into this:

```
python --version
Python 3.6.2
```

And what I want is this:

```
$ python --version

Python 3.6.2
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For HTML output you could add an [export filter](http://orgmode.org/manual/Advanced-configuration.html) like

```
(defun my-html-dollar-sign-filter (text backend info)
  "Add a $ sign to the beginning of code blocks"
  (when (org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'html)
        (replace-regexp-in-string
         "\\(<pre class=\"src src-sh\">\\)" "\\1$ " text)))

(add-to-list 'org-export-filter-src-block-functions
             'my-html-dollar-sign-filter)
```

which workes sinces `<pre class="src src-sh">python --version</pre>` identifies the command pretty unambiguously in the HTML output. Unfortunately the Latex exporter wraps both code and result in a `verbatim` environment which makes it impossible to only put a dollar sign in front of the code this way.

Comment: Thanks. I want to export to GitHub flavored markdown